# No VM guests are running outdated hypervisor (qemu) binaries on this host

Tags: ubuntu, aws-cli

```
curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
```

i have used above command to transfer the awslive.zip file
for installation of awscli then i have perform

```
root@x.x.x.x:/#sudo aws/install 
You can now run:/usr/local/bin/aws --version
aws-cli/2.13.21 Python/3.11.5 Linux/5.19.0-1025-aws exe/x86_64.ubuntu.22 prompt/off
```

but when i run show pkg not installed can anyone help on this
`root@x.x.x.x:/#dpkg -l awscli` it does not show ver & description

Comment: It's not an error. It's just a notice that there are no problems with qemu VMs. Whatever your problem is, you need to provide relevant information.

Comment: Please show actual error messages you encounter, without your interpretation. What do you get when you just run `/usr/local/bin/aws --version`?

Comment: It would be normal that `dpkg -l awscli` doesn't show anything,  since it wasn't installed with dpkg.

Comment: Related question - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410699/apt-upgrade-on-aarch64-reports-no-vm-guests-are-running-outdated-hypervisor